# play framework unresolved dependency with mysql connector

Tags: jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0

First of I am using the play framework (Java) version 2.38. I am trying to connect MySQL to my application and it is giving me an unresolved dependency error. I have looked at all threads here on this topic and nothing has worked, this is what I have...

**Application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=""
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.6.24")
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := """TestApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
   "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.6.24"
)

libraryDependencies += "org.json" % "json" % "20141113"


fork in run := true
```

The error I am getting is the following

```
 Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: 
mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.6.24: not found
Invalid response.
Invalid response.
Invalid response.
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0

See complete log in C:\Users\testingapp\.IntelliJIdea14
```

\system\log\sbt.last.log

I do not know if I am doing something wrong or if the SBT is failing somewhere, any suggestions?

Comment: Are your sure you've set the correct version of the mysql-connector-java dependency?
Checking Maven Central [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22mysql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mysql-connector-java%22) the latest version is: `5.1.35`

Comment: You are correct spend all day on the issue when the problem was so easy to fix. I was under the impression that the database version goes there, thanks a lot.

Comment: For details which driver works for which version you can check the MySQL compatibility chart as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL java connector versions don't correlate to MySQL server versions.
See [MySQL Connector/J compatibility chart](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html) for details.

The latest `mysql-connector-java` version for MySQL >= 4.0 as of writing is `5.1.35` (see [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22mysql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mysql-connector-java%22)).

You should change your dependency declaration accordingly.

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35"
```